# How to override the currency symbol used by Intl.NumberFormat

Tags: javascript, localization, react-intl, numberformatter

I am using the [`Intl.NumberFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat) to format currencies on a web page, but I want to use specific currency symbols instead of the locale defined ones.

To be more specific, I want to show `C$` for Canadian dollars, instead of the standard `$`, even though the locale is set to `en-CA` or `fr-CA`.

Example:

```js
> Intl.NumberFormat('en-CA', { style: 'currency', currency: 'CAD' }).format(13999.59)
'$13,999.59'  // expected 'C$13,999.59'

> Intl.NumberFormat('fr-CA', { style: 'currency', currency: 'CAD' }).format(13999.59)
'13 999,59 $' // expected '13 999,59 C$'
```

I suppose there is a way to *override* the currency symbol, but I couldn't find how in the docs.

So, how can I override the currency symbol for a specific locale?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It is possible with `Intl.NumberFormat.prototype.formatToParts()` method.

[View the documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/formatToParts)

```js
const enCA = Intl.NumberFormat('en-CA', { style: 'currency', currency: 'CAD' }).formatToParts(13999.59).map(({ type, value }) => {
    switch (type) {
      case "currency":
        return `C$`;
      default:
        return value;
    }
  }).reduce((str, pt) => str + pt);
  
const frCA = Intl.NumberFormat('fr-CA', { style: 'currency', currency: 'CAD' }).formatToParts(13999.59).map(({ type, value }) => {
    switch (type) {
      case "currency":
        return `C$`;
      default:
        return value;
    }
  }).reduce((str, pt) => str + pt);

console.log(enCA);
console.log(frCA);
```

Comment: What I was actually looking for was how to change the behavior of the `format` method with some config option. But thanks for the answer anyway.